# Relation between rows using a unique number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a relation between 4 rows. I need this for row to have a unique number. 
Also in my next insert not giving the same number again.

Example

```
ID   Name    uniqueNumber
-------------------------
 1   test1       1
 2   test2       1
 3   test3       1
 4   test4       1
 5   test1       5
 6   test2       5
 7   test3       5
 8   test4       5
```

I need some how to create a relation between rows under the same scope.

I was wondering if I can use the first insert row id, and use it in next 3.
Is there this option in SQL Server?

Comment: Use a Sequence? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please, post the expected result as well.

Comment: I need to insert this rows and after a specific number of rows to take the id of one and filling the rest of them. This 8 rows will be inserted at the same time after the same scope

Comment: Is this something you need to automatically happen on insert, or can you apply the "relation" later with an update, or do you need it on a select statement later?

Comment: What is "scope"?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the other comments and answers, I don't see how a sequence would be useful here. If you need a select, this query should work.

```
select 
    ID,
    Name,   
    case when ID % 4 = 0 then ID -3 else (ID - ID % 4) + 1 end as UniqueNumber
from YourTable
```

Or you could update your table later with the following query.

```
update YourTable
set UniqueNumber = case when ID % 4 = 0 then ID -3 else (ID - ID % 4) + 1 end
```

This produces output like so.

```
1   test1   1
2   test2   1
3   test3   1
4   test4   1
5   test1   5
6   test2   5
7   test3   5
8   test4   5
9   test1   9
10  test2   9
11  test3   9
12  test4   9
13  test1   13
14  test2   13
15  test3   13
16  test4   13
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me what 're you really want to do, but here is what I think of

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id) % 4 UniqueNumber
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1,'test1'),
  (2,'test2'),
  (3,'test3'),
  (4,'test4'),
  (5,'test1'),
  (6,'test2'),
  (7,'test3'),
  (8,'test4')
) T(Id, Name)
ORDER BY Id
```

Returns:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | UniqueNumber |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | test1 |            1 |
|  2 | test2 |            1 |
|  3 | test3 |            1 |
|  4 | test4 |            1 |
|  5 | test1 |            2 |
|  6 | test2 |            2 |
|  7 | test3 |            2 |
|  8 | test4 |            2 |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Or maybe a better way using a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySec
    AS INT   
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1  
    MINVALUE 1  
    MAXVALUE 4  
    CYCLE;

CREATE TABLE T(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Name VARCHAR(45),
  UniqueNumber  INT DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR MySec)
);

INSERT T(Name)
  VALUES
  ('test1'),
  ('test2'),
  ('test3'),
  ('test4'),
  ('test1'),
  ('test2'),
  ('test3'),
  ('test4');

SELECT * FROM T;
```

A better way using a computed column as

```
CREATE TABLE TT(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Name VARCHAR(45),
  UniqueNumber AS (Id - (Id - 1) % 4) 
);

INSERT TT(Name)
  VALUES
  ('test1'),
  ('test2'),
  ('test3'),
  ('test4'),
  ('test1'),
  ('test2'),
  ('test3'),
  ('test4'),
  ('test1'),
  ('test2'),
  ('test3'),
  ('test4'),
  ('test1'),
  ('test2'),
  ('test3'),
  ('test4');

SELECT * FROM TT;
```

Comment: This is totally different. According to the OP Id seems to be the auto-generated may be identity key and he need the logic to generate the UniqueNumber like 1, 5 and so on.

Comment: @SurajKumar As I stated, it wasn't clear to me. Check out the updates.